# How to count unqiue combinations of interactions between rows in excel?

Tags: excel

So I've running into some trouble hopefully someone can help, I'm trying to model weather.

Im trying to count the number of times certain interactions happen between categoric data in excel, example data set:

```
     Sunny
     Sunny
     Cloudy
     P-Cloudy
     Sunny 
     Rainy
     Cloudy
     Sunny
     Sunny 
     Etc...
```

So on the first day its sunny, the second day its sunny, the third its cloudy and so forth.  How would I count the number of times each weather type changes, i.e.

```
  Sunny to Sunny     2
  Sunny to P-Cloudy  0
  Sunny to Cloudy    1  
  Sunny to Rainy     1
  Cloudy to P-Cloudy 1 
  Cloudy to Sunny    1
  Cloudy to Rainy    0   Etc..
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Row   A         B       C        D                            E                             F                           G
1     Today     Tomorrow                        
2     Sunny     =A3              Sunny                        Cloudy                        P-Cloudy                    Rainy
3     Sunny     =A4     Sunny    =COUNTIFS(a:a,$D3,b:b,E$2) =COUNTIFS(a:a,$D3,b:b,F$2)  =COUNTIFS(a:a,$D3,b:b,G$2)  =COUNTIFS(a:a,$D3,b:b,H$2)
4     Cloudy    =A5     Cloudy   =COUNTIFS(a:a,$D4,b:b,E$2) =COUNTIFS(a:a,$D4,b:b,F$2)  =COUNTIFS(a:a,$D4,b:b,G$2)  =COUNTIFS(a:a,$D4,b:b,H$2)
5     P-Cloudy  =A6     P-Cloudy =COUNTIFS(a:a,$D5,b:b,E$2) =COUNTIFS(a:a,$D5,b:b,F$2)  =COUNTIFS(a:a,$D5,b:b,G$2)  =COUNTIFS(a:a,$D5,b:b,H$2)
6     Sunny     =A7     Rainy    =COUNTIFS(a:a,$D6,b:b,E$2) =COUNTIFS(a:a,$D6,b:b,F$2)  =COUNTIFS(a:a,$D6,b:b,G$2)  =COUNTIFS(a:a,$D6,b:b,H$2)
7     Rainy     =A8                     
8     Cloudy    =A9                     
9     Sunny     =A10                        
10    Sunny
```

I hope that this helps. :)

Ok I would hate to rewrite this but all Column references I would make them Absolute ($A:$A & $B:$B) just to make copy and pasting easier.

That being said the Vertical list of days in Column C is the Today Column, and Row 2 list is the weather transitioned to next

Answer (score 0):

- Just put your input in columnA.
- Column B shows the transition from one weather to another.
- Column C & D shows shows it in sorted order with the number of
  occurances(but has duplicates)
- Column **F & G are your final result**.

Sub model_weather()

```
lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1

For i = 1 To lastrow
Cells(i, 1) = Trim(Cells(i, 1))
Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i, 1) & " to " & Cells(i + 1, 1)
Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 1) & " to " & Cells(i + 1, 1)
Next

Range("C1:C" & lastrow).Sort Key1:=Range("C1:C" & lastrow), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

temp = 1

For i = 1 To lastrow
If Cells(i, 3) = Cells(i + 1, 3) Then
temp = temp + 1
Else: temp = 1
End If
Cells(i, 4) = temp
Next

Range("C1:D" & lastrow).Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("C1"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                   Key2:=Range("D1"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                   Header:=xlNo, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
x = 1
For i = 1 To lastrow
If Cells(i, 3) <> Cells(i + 1, 3) Then
Cells(x, 6) = Cells(i, 3)
Cells(x, 7) = Cells(i, 4)
x = x + 1
End If
Next

End Sub
```

[image]